# How should someone release their proof to the world?

Tags: proof-writing, education, publishing

Lets say someone (a reputable or non reputable mathematician) has come up with a remarkable one page proof to a famous maths problem.

Lets say the proof is likely correct but hasn't been released to the scrutiny of other mathematicians.

What would be the best way to release the proof to the world?

Comment: If it hasn't been released to the scrutiny of other mathematicians then to release it to the world can be a rather reckless step: even Wiles, after presenting his supposed demonstration of FLT, had to back off for a while because of an apparently fatal flaw, and without the help of R. Taylor it is very likely that we'd still be waiting and searching for a proof.

Comment: If it's just one page, post it here.

Comment: Or in the margin, if it will fit...

Comment: **Not here.** This site is not the appropriate place for that.

Comment: What's wrong with asking whether one's proof is correct?  I thought those type of questions were allowed here.

Comment: or maybe send me to check by email!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write a paper, post it on the arXiv, send it to a journal.